# Difference between return value of a funciton

Tags: postgresql

What will be the result of  `quote_ident(table_name::text)` and what is the difference if we pass it rather than table in a pipeline statement?
For e.g is there difference between

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_stm AFTER ' || stm_targets || ' ON ' || quote_ident(table_name::text) ...
```

and this

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_stm AFTER ' || stm_targets || ' ON ' || table_name ...
```

Comment: Could you expand that question with an example of how you want to use it? What do you mean by *pipeline statement*?

Comment: Yes,I gave an example

Comment: You cannot use an expression in this context. [The syntaxt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html) is clear:

Comment: It depends on what the `table_name` variable's/parameter's type is actually. If its an `oid` ([`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) more specifically), than casting to text & calling `quote_ident()` makes it worse (oid types used in text/string context will properly escape table names & will use schema qualifiers when needed). If i'ts a textual data, than casting to `text` makes no difference (and using quote_ident() in that case is almost a requirement against SQL injection f.ex; see [LaurenzAlbe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39207510/1499698)'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that without using `quote_ident` your composed statement becomes invalid if `table_name` contains spaces, double quotes or other niceties (or is a reserved SQL keyword).

Moreover, using `quote_ident` saves you from SQL injection if `table_name` comes from an untrusted source.